# Can JS lib can be use in Native Tizen App?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app

I want to build an application which need to show statstical data in form of Charts. As i am not able to find any suitable lib/ way/api  by which I can draw chart like PIE chart,Bar chart , Line chart. In web application we can use JS libs which can draw charts according to my requirement.

Here is an example using chartJS lib.

https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/create-animated-charts-chart.js

which is devlope in Web Application.

Can I use this JS lib for developing the same in Native App ? I think this is not possible directly. If there is any way please let me know. Or is there any Library which can be use for developing same requirement  in Native App.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a webview to your app and use ChartJS.

---

If there are charts you like in any of the apps you have it would be worthwhile checking if the apps are open source and if yes, you can check the code to see how they do charting.

Here are a couple of them

1. https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android (for Android)
2. https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart (for Android and there is a link to an iOS version as well - https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts)

   - many more

You will want to first check out whether you like the visualizations and then check out if there is enough documentation / community support in case you run into any issues.